# Attachment access using ESRI's dynamic services

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I need to be able to display photo attachments in a tabbed popup window that ideally only contains a dynamic map service. I have a working demo running that uses a dynamic map to display the data and several feature services to gain access to the photo attachments and it works but I'd like to know if this is the only way to do it or if there's a simpler way...ie not having to use a Feature Service? The demo map only has two simple polygon's so it isn't that bad but my production map would have over 20 layers to loop though and there's a LOT of complex geometry so pushing that all out as a FS has proven to be much slower than a dynamic service.

The demo map I have running is available here: http://maps.ducks.ca/pmv

If do I have to utilize the FS method is there a better way than I've done here or is there someway to use the "showAttachments: True" option in the Popup properties?